# reading data from server arduino and gsm900a

Tags: arduino-uno, gsm

I am facing a problem in reading data from thingspeak server
after each AT command, I get the right response from the gsm
However, after

```
AT+HTTPPARA = "URL","thingspeak.com/channels/channelNumber/fields/1/last.txt"
AT+HTTPACTION=0
AT+HTTPREAD
```

I always get the response as HTML code so not as content
I really need your help and will appreciate any suggestions.
Thanks in advance.